# Error when using Deselect/Select All tool?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Whenever I try to use the Deselect/Select All tool I get this error:

[image: Error screenshot]

What do I do so I can use the tool without getting this error?

Comment: It's definitely a bug report but usually I think it's standard to select and deselect in Object mode and/or Edit mode.  I tried to get that error by using 'a' in Texture Paint mode but it's not happening for me.

Comment: @MarcClintDion Swapping to Edit Mode fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried using box select while in Texture Paint to reproduce the error so I could report it but nothing I do causes the failure you posted in that screenshot.  I did however find a new way to zoom in on objects while I was trying to cause Blender to fail.  Shift-B does a box select zoom. nice.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that if I swap from Texture Paint to Edit Mode that I can simply press *B*, and select what I need.

[image: Fix]